# Can I run python 3.5 scripts in windows without python installed?

Tags: python, windows, batch-file, python-3.5

I have this script written in Python 3.5 and I need to run it in a windows 7 PC. 
The problem is that this PC does not have Python installed.
Is there a way of converting the .py to an extension that windows can run?
Or is there a way of converting the .py file to .bat or something like that?

Thanks!

Comment: Python is an interpreted language.  So the interpreter is needed to run the script.

Comment: [PyInstaller](http://www.pyinstaller.org/) should work. It has a lot of options and a learning curve, but I have used it successfully.

Answer (score 2):

py2exe should handle situations such as this. Directly from the tutorial site it says:

"py2exe turns Python programs into packages that can be run on other Windows computers without needing to install Python on those computers."

Source: http://www.py2exe.org/index.cgi/Tutorial

Comment: Yeah, but it doesn't support Python 3.5. Only up to 3.4

Comment: I can't speak for every use case, but I was able to use it on a simple Python 3.5 program and it worked as expected.